# angular oauth oidc with keycloak redirects with the session and state embeded in the URL

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, keycloak, angular-oauth2-oidc

**I have integrated my angular application with keycloak identity server, after i login i redirect it to the layout module but it redrects it to the url with the session state like (http://localhost:4200/dashboard?state=ekd0MWVVeTBLLmhudjNfci1QMzFLNmotUUtKRGlCYmhSR3dqUElhV1RYT1Ay&session_state=f96c557f-8120) . but what i want is to redirect to localhost:4200/dashboard, how can i acheive this. is there anything that i missed on my code configration or files ?**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZt7v.png)

```
export const authCodeFlowConfig: AuthConfig = {
  issuer: environment.authConfig.issuer,
  tokenEndpoint: environment.authConfig.redirectUri,
  redirectUri: window.location.origin,
  useSilentRefresh: true,
  clientId: environment.authConfig.clientId,
  responseType: environment.authConfig.responseType,
  scope:environment.authConfig.scope,
  showDebugInformation: environment.authConfig.showDebugInformation,
};
export function initializeKeycloak(oauthService: OAuthService):Promise<void> {
    return new Promise((resolve)=>
    {
      oauthService.configure(authConfig);
      oauthService.setupAutomaticSilentRefresh();
      oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndLogin()
      .then(()=>resolve());
      
    });
  }

export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
      path: '',
      loadChildren: () => import('./modules/layout/layout.module').then((m) => m.LayoutModule),
    },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'error/404' },
  ];
  


export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(
      appRoutes,    
      withPreloading(PreloadAllModules)
      ),
    provideHttpClient(),
    provideOAuthClient(),
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: (oauthService:OAuthService)=>{
        return ()=>{
          initializeKeycloak(oauthService);
        }
      },
      multi: true,
      deps:[
        OAuthService
      ]
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass:AuthInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
    importProvidersFrom(OAuthModule.forRoot({
      resourceServer: {
          allowedUrls: [environment.apiUrl],
          sendAccessToken: true
      }
  }))
  ],
};
```

i want it to redirect it to localhost:4200/dashboard without the session state.

Comment: I have no idea of `keycloak identity server` but i have worked with `microsoft identitty server` and `angular` to implement o-auth in that what I did was create a component let's say `auth-callback`. so I redirect user there after login is completed and on `ngOnInit` I have redirected user to home page. Let me know if you need example how I did that.